# Question about a theorem of integration

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

In Darboux integration, If $f$ is a bounded function on $[a,b]$, then $L(f)\le U(f)$ where $L(f),U(f)$ are the lower and upper Darboux integral. My question is why it requires $f$ to be bounded?

Comment: Because U(f) **does not exist** if f is not upper bounded, for example.

Comment: Echoing @did's comment, $L,U$ have terms like $\inf_{x \in I_k} f(x), \sup_{x \in I_k} f(x)$ where the intervals $I_k$ cover $[a,b]$. If $f$ is unbounded above, then one of the $\sup$s will be infinite and hence so will the sum. Similarly if $f$ is unbounded below.

Comment: @copper.hat but it still valids if $\sup f(X)=\infty$

Comment: Well, to be integrable, you need $\sup L(f,\pi) = \inf U(f,\pi)$. If both are $\infty$, the resulting integral seems to have little analytical value. One would be better off taking $f_M = \max(\min(f,M),-M)$ and seeing if $\int f_M$ converges. This would be more useful from an analytical perspective (my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

In the sense of the extended line order, the inequality  $L(f)\le U(f)$ holds for any real-valued function. The reason one restricts attention to bounded functions is that the direct evaluation of the Darboux integral does not yield valuable information for unbounded functions. For example, consider $x^{-1/2}$ on $[0,1]$: here the upper Darboux integral is $\infty$ because for all partitions $U(f)=\infty$. Yet, this is a convergent improper integral - but one has to treat it as such, by considering smaller intervals on which the function is bounded.